# installation Aquasim in ns2

Tags: ns2

i am having problem with my ns2 emulator.
when i run broadcastMAC_example.tcl file it gives error: invalid command name "Mac/UnderwaterMac"
When I run vbf_example_5.tcl file it gives error: invalid command name "Agent/Vectorbasedforward"
i am using ubuntu 16.04 and ns2.30
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5cBW.png)

i used the command:
$sudo make install and $make install
They appear with the same error:
for d in /usr/local/man/man1; do 
if [ ! -d $d ]; then 
mkdir -p $d ;
fi;
done
/usr/bin/install -c -m 755 ns /usr/local/bin
/usr/bin/install: cannot stat 'ns': No such file or directory
Makefile:522: recipe for target 'install-ns' failed
make: *** [install-ns] Error 1
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWl15.png)

Answer (score 0):

> invalid command name "Mac/UnderwaterMac"

Seems you are using a wrong copy of the executable 'ns'.
Or you have a failed build :  Ubuntu 16.04 - amd64 *cannot* build Aqua-Sim.
But you can install the app `aquasim-ns2_2.30-1ubuntu14_amd64.deb` (1.6MB) into Ubuntu 16.04 - amd64
https://drive.google.com/file/d/19mpMQvuA2Fbud1MCMagCdHEUbe3OkTLW/view?usp=sharing
Provides  `/usr/local/bin/ns230-Aqua-el6`
Download ..... and install

```
sudo apt install Downloads/aquasim-ns2_2.30-1ubuntu14_amd64.deb
```

--------- Simulation -------
`ns230-Aqua-el6  vbf_example_5.tcl`
43 simulation examples: `aquasim-examples-01.20.tar.gz`
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-j-2mFFOsVqVHTEVEdKxboG75Mi4pO7A/view?usp=sharing

Building "Aqua-Sim" : A specific 32bit / 64bit OS is required :
The ancient Ubuntu 10.10 - i386 or the modern CentOS  6.10 - i386  / CentOS  6.10 - x86_64
https://vault.centos.org/6.10/isos/i386/CentOS-6.10-i386-LiveDVD.iso
https://vault.centos.org/6.10/isos/x86_64/CentOS-6.10-x86_64-LiveDVD.iso

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the app aquasim-ns2_2.30-1ubuntu14_amd64.deb and executed the command
$sudo apt install aquasim-ns2_2.30-1ubuntu14_amd64
but it gives an error saying file not found:
E: Unable to locate package aquasim-ns2_2.30-1ubuntu14_amd64
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'aquasim-ns2_2.30-1ubuntu14_amd64'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'aquasim-ns2_2.30-1ubuntu14_amd64'

my system:
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Kernel: Linux 4.15.0-142-generic

Comment: Please check package presence: `$ ls Downloads/` ..... When you are sure that a package is downloaded: `$ cd Downloads/ && sudo apt install ./aquasim-ns2_2.30-1ubuntu14_amd64.deb` .......... P.S.: Answers are for solutions, not for "further issues" : Please use comments for that.

Comment: I made sure I downloaded it and put it in the download file